# Hand-crafted PDF considered wrong by Acrobat even though it passes online validation

Tags: pdf, syntax

I have hand-crafted one PDF (https://media.24usoftware.com/d/PDFwithOnlyLink.pdf) and modified another one, generated from FileMaker, in order to add web link annotations (https://media.24usoftware.com/d/PDFwithLinks.pdf). They both pass validation at https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx, but for some reason when I open them in Adobe Reader they get immediately modified, so when I try to close them Adobe Reader asks me if I want to save changes. But I have no clue what the changes are and why they were made. Any ideas? Adobe's support claims there are syntax errors but without providing any details what's syntactically wrong in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your hand-crafted PDF file Ghostscript says your xref table is wrong, some of the entries are not exactly 20 bytes. This is a requirement for an entry in the xref table, if you use \r or \n instead of \r\n for an xref entry (as you have done) you must pad out the entry with white space.

I get the same warning on your modified file too.

See page 94 of the 1.7 PDF Reference Manual where it says:

> Each entry is exactly 20 bytes long, including the end-of-line marker.

and then later:

> If the file’s end-of-line marker is a single character (either a
> carriage return or a line feed), it is preceded by a single space; if
> the marker is 2 characters (both a carriage return and a line feed),
> it is not preceded by a space. Thus, the overall length of the entry
> is always exactly 20 bytes.

You might want to think about using a different validation tool, this is a basic and **very** common error, if that validator can't find it it doesn't speak well for its quality.

Though I'm disappointed to see that Acrobat X Pro's own validation analyser can't find it either.....

Comment: Yes, it's the good ol' wrong xref entry size issue. But many validators appear to start validating only after reading the PDF objects into memory, making them ignore any issues they overlooked while reading.

Comment: Thanks so much for your analysis. I didn't notice the 20 bytes requirement in the spec. Now I was able to fix it just by adding the extra white space!